Manifest V3: How to enable my DLP chromium extension on other chrome/edge browers plugins
My DLP extension monitors and analyzes all the data entered by users on web pages. However, it doesn’t seem to monitor data entered in the Edge Co-pilot plugin or other plugins, possibly because the extension isn’t active within the plugin. Do you know how to activate the extension for other plugins?
I tried different setting in Manifest V, but nothing worked.

Try Can you access chrome:// pages from an extension?
